# High power dc/dc converter (or voltage clamping) with high source impedance

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, voltage-clipping

**Short version:**

I have a DC voltage source (adjustable up to 750 V 60 A) that is powering our robot which expects 320 V nominal (never exceed at 360 V) and can consume up to 30-35 A (but only 30 mA when idle).

The problem is it is connected by a very long cable (8 Ω, rough estimation of 160 µH (to be measured next time we open the corresponding part of the robot)).

Currently the supply is at 350 V. But when drawing high current, the voltage drops significantly (to the point that putting motors at 100% PWM decrease the mechanical power).

**Question:** how best to provide more power to the robot? Either powering above 360 V and clamping the voltage (i.e. regulating down to 320-350 until bellow this voltage, then accepting the voltage drop) or regulating the voltage directly?

**Long version:**

We are working on a underwater robot.

Power supply: a high power lab supply, up to 750 VDC 60 A (adjustable voltage, current limit, power limit)

Cable: resistance (both directions combined): 8 Ω. I estimated roughly the inductance at 160 µH (I will measure it next time we open the robot). Power dissipation in the cable (in the sense overheating) is not an issue (long distance, and in water). Changing the cable is not an option we explored, but we couldn't find any that is better electrically and still acceptable mechanically.

Load: the robot is nominally 320 V, with a never exceed of 360 V. If voltage drops bellow 320 V, the motors can no longer deliver as much power as nominal. Current consumption varies from 30 mA (idle) to 30-35 A full loaded (theoretical, we the current cable we don't manage to get that high).

Issue: as soon as we draw more than 4 A, the voltage drops bellow the 320 V nominal, and the mechanical power decreases far bellow the expected power at "full load", we get only about half the nominal power out of our motors due to the voltage drop in the cable.

Question: what "simple" solution/technology should I investigate to increase the available power? NB: it is NOT a requirement to keep 320 V at full load (even if it is a plus), but it voltage should remain around 320 V up to at least 12-15 A.

So far, the ideas I had:

- voltage clamping (solution 1): put the supply voltage at 450 V, and switch power resistors in series with the robot to reduce the voltage. (optionally: switching at high frequency + capacitors, in order to reduce the number of different resistors needed). Above 16 A, no resistor is put in series, and the voltage will drop bellow 320 V due to the cable resistance
- voltage clamping (solution 2): put the supply voltage at 450 V, add a MOSFET between the cable and the robot, and switch it (high frequency) to reduce the voltage (adding 2 capacitor, one to absorb the inductive spikes, the other one to smooth the output voltage). This solution needs a lot of capacitors to handle the huge ripple current (each bloc needs to support the full current of the robot (at least to the point where we stop switching, i.e. around 15 A)
- voltage clamping (solution 3): mixing option 1 and 2 (having one MOSFET directly + 1 with a resistor in series): this way, the current capacity of the capacitors can be reduced
- using a higher input voltage (maybe 700-750 V) and using a DC/DC converter to regulate down to 320 V. Electrically, this would be the best solution I think, but I'm unsure how big/heavy/complicated this might get (I never designed a buck converter myself for for than 50 W, and then just following the design guide). If taking this option, what topology should I investigate? The classical buck converter? Is there anything particular to take into account due to the high cable resistance/inductance?

Some additional constraints:

- voltage ripple is not a very hard constraint (I would say 5 V is a complete non-issue, if more, I will investigate further to what the exact limit is)
- current steps can be the full range (i.e. 30 A to 30 mA or the other way round). I don't have the exact duration for those steps, but I would guess around 10 ms (if this becomes a critical factor, I will have to think about how to measure this duration, as I need the robot to be in water to consume 30 A, and at the supply side the current might get smoothed by the cable inductance : probably I will need to build a test setup with a short cable so I can measure at the supply side).
- efficiency in itself is a plus, but not a major point. However, thermal dissipation at the robot side is to be taken into account.
- in air, the robot consumes max 3.5 A (underwater, the current can be far more important, but we now get water-cooling for the enclosures)
- the enclosure is likely to be filled with insulating oil (which should also help to conduct heat to the watertight enclosure)
- size and weight are important factors (making that so far we haven't found and off the shelf regulator that fits our needs). For the "main" PCB, max size is about 10*10*7 cm (a bit bigger might still be possible, a bit smaller is a plus), the temperature of the insulating oil should not exceed 70°C (nb: only this PCB is dissipating heat). In addition, we should be able to add a 2 smaller enclosures for power resistors (lets say 7*7*5cm) where the temperature might rise far higher (lets say 80°C on the outside of the enclosure). Note that adding those extra enclosures will represent approx. 500$ extra. For the weight, <1 kg would be great, <5 kg should be acceptable.
- cost is not very important (very small series, high added value). Cost <1000$ is perfect, I expect costs up to about 5000$ to still be OK if need.
- reliability and development time matter far more than cost
- in case it is easier, it should also be possible to replace the lab supply by a 3 phase transformer (with whatever output voltage), and supply the robot with 3 phase AC to be rectified and converted to 320 VDC

So what technologies/topology/circuits should I look into for this application?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149761/discussion-on-question-by-sandro-high-power-dc-dc-converter-or-voltage-clamping); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.